# Character Decomposition of Permutation Representation

Tags: representation-theory

This question has already been asked on this site before. Here is the link to the question - [Regular representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599943/regular-representation).
My doubt is regarding the answer.As far as I know the 6 permutation matrices mentioned in the answer must be of order 6 as the basis is $D_3$ itself and in this case I am getting the decomposition as $\chi_{per}$= $3\chi_{1}$+$\chi_{2}$+$\chi_{3}$
where $\chi_{1}$,$\chi_{2}$ and $\chi_{3}$ are the same notations as given in the answer.
Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I get the same answer as you. The answer in the linked post is evidently wrong by dimension reasons (as you note).

Comment: Thanks for the verification.